# Алгоритм добавления в избранные

Tags: алгоритм, php, оптимизация, mysql

Доброго времени суток.
На днях я подумал о функции добавления в избранные.
У нас имеется:

- Страница, со строками, имеющими свои ID
- База данных с таблицами отдельными для строк и пользователей

Теперь мне нужно, чтобы пользователь мог добавлять строку себе в избранные.
Сначала я думал сделать в таблице `users` столбец fav и туда писать id тех строк, которые пользователь выбрал. Это имело бы примерно такой вид:

```
5,23,135,1,34,78,94,2
```

А при каждой новой добавленной строки, проходила функция, которая проверяла бы наличие этой строки в избранных.

Мне показалось, что это достаточно долго для выполнения скрипта, так что хотелось бы почитать советы, которые помогли бы написать лучший алгоритм.

*p.s. Система на php + MySQL*

Comment: Да! Почему-то мне в голову это не пришло. Спасибо за идею.
Оформите свой комментарий как ответ, чтобы я его принял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что мешает добавить таблицу user_favs (id, user_id, fav_id) ?